# Updating prebuilt SQL database in Android Studio

Tags: android, sql

I have a simple Android App that just displays data from a SQL database built with DB Browser.
When I change the content of the database in DB Browser, and then Copy/Paste the db file in the asset folder of my App (overwriting the previous version of the db), the data displayed in the App doesn't change...
I tried incrementing the version number but it didn't worked... Any suggestions ?

Comment: dbbrowser is just a software to view your db files. Lean some tutorial for SQLite db that is what you will use on a basic level forupdating your db code.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. It seems like you need to migrate your database (that is modification in DB structure).
I assume you have used SQLite or Room.

If you used SQLite then use

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
```

is used to migration. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488813/how-to-do-database-schema-migrations-in-android)

If you have used Room then refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions)

Edit:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static DbHelper sDbHelper;

        private MyDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, *DATABASE_NAME*, null, *DATABASE_VERSION*);
        }

        public static DbHelper getInstance() {
            if (sDbHelper == null) {
                sDbHelper = new DbHelper(Axonator.getContext());
            }
            return sDbHelper;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            MigrationV0ToV1 mV1 = new MigrationV0ToV1();
            mV1.run(db);
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            if (oldVersion < 1) {
                //means old version is 0, major change
                MigrationV0ToV1 migration = new MigrationV0ToV1();
                migration.run(db);
            }
        }
```

Sppose you have version(`DATABASE_VERSION`) is 0 then you want to modify DB structure then increment `DATABASE_VERSION` to 1.

```
public class MigrationV0ToV1 {
    
    public void run(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //deleteTables(db);
        //createTables(db);
        //modifyTables(tb)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this warm welcome :) There is something odd with my onUpgrade, which is that it doesnt run when I increment the version number... I'll read through your links

Comment: Check edited answer. This is basic logic about sqlite migration.